# Why does my css code file have my html source when I open developers tool on google chrome?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I have the following problem when I run my web application, the HTML source code appears to be in the css file on chrome developers tool:

I have my HTML file called index.html and the following in the source.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Node</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" title="Default Styles" 
   media="screen">


 </head>

 <body>
    <h1> Welcome to my first node.js Website </h1>

    <h2> this is how you and where you do the mark up in node js</h2>





    <!-- footer -->
    <div class= "base">
        <footer>
            <nav>

            </nav>
        </footer>
    </div>


</body>
  </html>
```

And the following is my CSS file called style.css

```
  html, body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  color: #fff; 

  }


 /*
footer 
 */

 .base{

  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.13);
  bottom: 0%;
  position: fixed;

  }
```

when I run this code on the local server and opening the developer's tool on google chrome 
I see that the HTML source code is in the CSS file.[![The CSS file now has the HTML source running on the local server][1]][1]

Here is my Node.js

```
  // Load the http module to create an http server.
    var http = require('http');
    var fs   = require('fs');




 var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   console.log('request was made:' + request.url);

  fs.readFile('index.html', function(err,data){
 response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
 response.write(data);
 response.end();
   });


 });



  // Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
     server.listen(8005);

   // send a  message on the terminal
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8005/");
```

Comment: what does your node server looklike?

Comment: @DanielA.White you mean the code that creates my node server?
here :
var http = require('http');
var fs   = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  console.log('request was made:' + request.url);
  
  fs.readFile('index.html', function(err,data){
     response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
     response.write(data);
     response.end();
  });
  
});
server.listen(8005);

console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8005/");

Comment: correct. that would help.

Comment: @DanielA.White any idea what's wrong?

Comment: please post it in your question.

Comment: @DanielA.White I just did.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your server request handler. You are manually sending `index.html` for every request made by the browser. When you navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8005/` your server sends `index.html` so far so good but then the browser sees `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" title="Default Styles"` and asks for `http://127.0.0.1:8005/style.css` but your server returns again `index.html` that's why it receives the content of `index.html` as it where `style.css`. You need to filter your requests to the server in order to respond with the correct file. In your case it could be like:

```js
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log('request was made:' + request.url);

  switch (request.url) {
    case '/':
      fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
        response.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
      });
      break;

    case '/style.css':
      fs.readFile('style.css', function(err, data) {
        response.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'text/css'
        });
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
      });
      break;

    default:
      response.end();
      break;
  }
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8005);

// send a  message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8005/");
```

Please note that this is a very basic server. It lacks error handling and is very hard to scale and maintain. Maybe you would like to try a node server framework like [express](https://expressjs.com)

Comment: How do I accomplish this? Can you provide an example

Comment: @Thanks ,I am very new to node.js

Comment: @ alexortizl Can you please point me to some good node.js tutorials

Comment: @slim sure. I think the best resource to learn node is to read the official docs https://nodejs.org/en/docs/ You can check express too https://expressjs.com it's a very popular  framework to build web servers. You can find guides there to get started with node and express.